# How can I load an image on button press?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to load an image from the web when a button is clicked. 
I have tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.ImageLocation = "http://i.imgur.com/7ikw7ye.png";
}
```

But I get the error:

> 'System.Drawing.Image' does not contain a definition for 'ImageLocation'

If anyone could help me fix this issue or find the correct way to do load an image when a button is clicked it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) doesn't have a property for ImageLocation; however, the [PictureBox class does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation.aspx).

So change your code to try this instead:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://i.imgur.com/7ikw7ye.png";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
pictureBox1.Load("http://i.imgur.com/7ikw7ye.png");
```

or LoadAsync to prevent your UI from freezing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ImageLocation, you are supposed to call Load() afterwards.

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://i.imgur.com/7ikw7ye.png";
pictureBox1.Load();
```

You can also try something like:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap("Image Path");
```